# How to query Tableau Metadata API with GraphQL query?

Tags: python, api, rest, tableau-api

I was able to sign-in just fine (with no certificate verification) using the REST API. However, when I query the Metadata API, all I get back is the html/javascript from the graphQL GUI. Does anyone how I could properly set up my query to retrieve the same information as shown in the GUI on /metadata/graphQL.

Here is my code to sign-in:

```html
import requests
import json

url = "https://<tableau-server-name>/api/3.8/auth/signin"

payload = json.dumps({
  "credentials": {
    "personalAccessTokenName": "<my login token>",
    "personalAccessTokenSecret": "<my token value>",
    "site": {
      "contentUrl": ""
    }
  }
})
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
response = json.loads(response.text)
    
print(response)
site_id = response['credentials']['site']['id']
user_id = response['credentials']['user']['id']
token = response['credentials']['token']

headers['X-tableau-auth']=token
```

I get a nice json response with the authorization token that I can pass for subsequent calls:

```html
{'credentials': {'site': {'id': '<site-id>', 'contentUrl': ''}, 'user': {'id': '<my-user-id>'}, 'token': '<my-user-token>'}}
```

The next call I make to the metadata api, here is where the problems start:

```html
import requests
import json

url = "https://<tableau-server-name>/metadata/graphql/"

payload="{\"query\":\"query getAllTables {\\r\\n  workbooks (filter: {id: \\\"<workbook id>"\\\"}) {\\r\\n\\t\\tname\\r\\n    dashboards {\\r\\n      id\\r\\n      name\\r\\n      sheets {\\r\\n        id\\r\\n        name\\r\\n      \\tdatasourceFields {\\r\\n          id \\r\\n          name\\r\\n          __typename\\r\\n          ...on CalculatedField {\\r\\n            formula\\r\\n          }\\r\\n        }\\r\\n      }\\r\\n    }\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\",\"variables\":{}}"
headers = {
  '\'X-tableau-auth\'': token,
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

The response is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="" xmlns:tb="">

<head ng-csp>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="vizportal-config" data-buildId="2020_2_164_widw5sl5zoo" data-staticAssetsUrlPrefix="">
    <link href="vendors-vizportal.css?c5da2e24bb179cf9a5dd" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vizportal.css?c5da2e24bb179cf9a5dd" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js?c5da2e24bb179cf9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js?c5dasdfasdfcf9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js?cadfasdff9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-cookies.min.js?cadfasdfsacf9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-sanitize.min.js?casdfasdfasdfb179cf9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rsa.js?c5da2easdfasdfasfasdfdd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js?adfasghdfhfdgdfacf9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="q.min.js?casdfdsfa9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas-to-blob.min.js?c5sdfasdfasdfafa5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.cookie.js?c5adsfasdf9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mousetrap.js?c5djdfghjrhfcff9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="core.min.js?c5dahkfghjfghj9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors-vizportal.js?c5da2e24bwtertcf9a5dd"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vizportal.js?c5da2e2dfghdfgha5dd"></script>
</head>

<body class="tb-body">
    <div class="tb-app" ng-app="VizPortalRun" id="ng-app" tb-window-resize>
        <tb:app></tb:app>
        <tb:react-toaster></tb:react-toaster>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="inline_stackedElement.html">
            <div class="tb-absolute" tb-window-resize tb-left="left" tb-top="top" tb-right="right" tb-bottom="bottom" tb-visible="visible" tb-overflow-y="overflowY"></div>
      </script>
        <tb:stacked-elements></tb:stacked-elements>
    </div>
</body>
```

By comparison, I am expecting the query to return json with the appropriate response to my graphql query which I tested in the graphQL GUI.

The graphQL query I am running is here:

```html
query getAllFields {
  workbooks (filter: {id: "<workbook-id>"}){
      embeddedDatasources {
    fields {
      id
      name
      ...on CalculatedField{
        formula
      }
    }
    name
    id
  }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but figured it out by reverse engineering the call from the GraphQL UI. Instead of

> **https://<tableau-server-name>/metadata/graphql/**

you need to use

> **https://<tableau-server-name>/relationship-service-war/graphql**

for your GraphQL query.

My authentication looks like this:

```
import requests, json

server_name = "<tableau-server-name>"
api_version = "<tableau-api-version>"
site_url_id = "<tableau-site-url>"

personal_access_token_name = "<your-personal-token-name>"
personal_access_token_secret = "<your-personal-token-secret>"

signin_url = f"https://{server_name}/api/{api_version}/auth/signin"
payload = { "credentials": { "personalAccessTokenName": personal_access_token_name, "personalAccessTokenSecret": personal_access_token_secret, "site": {"contentUrl": site_url_id }}}
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}

req = requests.post(signin_url, json=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)

response = json.loads(req.content)
token = response["credentials"]["token"]
site_id = response["credentials"]["site"]["id"]

headers['X-tableau-auth'] = token
```

GraphQL queries can be made by using the following code:

```
query = """
query tableauUsers {
  tableauUsers {
    id
  }
}
"""

url = f'https://{server_name}/relationship-service-war/graphql'
request_body = {'query': query}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=request_body, verify=False)
dma_views_response = json.loads(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, until I realized that the url needs to contain "api"

`url = "https://<tableau-server-name>/api/metadata/graphql/"`